# How to Change the Datasource that an Element is Bound to in Android

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I would like to be able to change the data source that an element is bound to.

For example, suppose I have a button's enabled property bound to some given property like this:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btnZero1"
   android:enabled="@{mSystem.item[0].Online }" />
```

This binds fine.  However, what if I want to dynamically change this binding to point to `mSystem.item[1]`.Online at runtime.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's possible. The variable's getter should have the @Bindable annotation in model class which you have passed in the layout's data tag.

Follow few steps:
1. Model class should extends the BaseObservable class.
2. Then you need to use the @Bindable with your variable's getter which you need to observe for dynamic changes. [It will generate the variable in your auto generated BR class]
3. Then, in the setter just use the notifyPropertyChanged(BR.your_variable_name)

By that way once you make change to your @Bindable variable it will observe for changes. As soon as you make any change to the models variable it will update the UI.